# Merge master into feature branch

Tags: git

I have the following branch structure:

```
     * master
   / | 
  /  | 
 *   | 
 *   | 
 *f1 | 
  \  |  *f2
   \ | / 
     *master
```

There were important updates in branch `f1` that have been merged into master and I'd like to use them in `f2`, even though `f2` isn't ready to merge into master.  I have tried:

```
git checkout f2
git merge master
```

and that didn't apply the changes to `f2`.

What am I missing?

Comment: What was the output of that command?

Comment: maybe you have the  changes in remote origin/master and not local master branch?

Comment: The output was `Already up-to-date`. This has me thinking that I maybe don't actually want to `merge`, but do something else instead.

Comment: @ebbishop - Ok, I would double-check Heisenberg's point.

Answer (score 0):

The command for this is

```
git checkout f2
git rebase merged
```

Comment: If `merge` didn't work (for whatever reason), then `rebase` is unlikely to work either.

Comment: He doesn't say anything about `merge` not working though... his `f2` is not yet _ready_ to be merged (development is not complete).

Comment: He did - "that didn't apply the changes to f2".

Comment: He tried `git merge master` where `master` seems to be (if his drawing is accurate) the old commit, while `merged` is the new commit (`master+f1`). So that merge is a no-op.

Comment: That is a fair point!  But in which case, the answer should really just be "you typed the wrong branch name".  (Though FWIW, it's unlikely that commit is really called `merged`, given the OP's explanation - "have been merged into master".)

Comment: `merged` was in fact the master branch, that had f1 merged into it. Not sure if this changes anyones answers. I edited the question

Comment: Well, then I'm confused and don't know how that would not merge into f2. Still, I would use rebase instead of merge for this (it is equivalent in the overall outcome, though, just a matter of preference). What happens if you use the commands I gave?